# How can I build a comments deck that randomly display 3 items in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I'm trying to build a way I can display names and comments that randomly select 3 rows from the dataset and display them in a presentable manner. Almost like a text dashboard.

An example of the data I have can be found below

[image: data]

I have a whole list of this data and I want to present it in an object that shows say 3 of them at a time and I can add enhancements to make it look great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to randomly select 3 rows of data from large datatable. to accomplish that, you can use this formula `=INDEX($A$13:$A$40,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A$13:$A$40)),1)` in cell `A2`, and this formula `=VLOOKUP($A2,$A$13:$B$40,2,FALSE)` in cell `B2`. Adjust ranges to fit your datatable.

[image]

Now every time you calculate spreadsheet, you will receive different set of rows in range `A2:B4`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I created a bit of a tweak to the same. Just added a random number index from 1 to 15 next to the datset and ran a vlookup on it. Although yours is much neater :). Thanks